# Read large amount of data

Tags: spring-batch

I'm having large amount of data (5 million ligne) to read from a table A. Then calculate some data and finally save in database in another table B. So it's consuming much time. My Spring-batch job have only one step (read, process and writer).
How i can parallelize my job to process 500 ligne by second ?

```java
@Bean
public Job myJob() {    
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
        .preventRestart()
                .listener(listener())
                .flow(myStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

@Bean
public Step myStep() {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
      .<ObjectDto, List<ObjectDto>>chunk(1)
      .reader(ItemReader)
      .processor(ItemProcessor)
      .writer(ItemWriter())
      .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the chunk size to 1. This means each record will be processed in a separate transaction which is probably the cause of your performance issue. Try to increase the chunk size so that you have less transactions, and you should notice a performance improvement.

Now to answer your question, there are multiple ways to scale a Spring Batch chunk-oriented step. The easiest one is probably using a [multi-threaded step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) where each chunk is processed by a separate thread.

Another option is to partition your table and use a [partitioned step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) where each partition is processed by a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud ! How I can partition my table ? Can you give me an example ?

Comment: You can partition the table by column range for example, take a look at the [ColumnRangePartitioner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/ColumnRangePartitioner.java#L36)